# Setting Synology DSM default CIFS permissions

Tags: permissions, samba, synology

I just recently got my first Synology NAS (DS213+) and am running DSM 4.3 on it. I still have a few days of tinkering to spend on it before I need to decide if I should exchange it for a QNAP or something else...

My problem is the file permissions. I have created users, created shared folders and set permissions on them to give read/write access to all my users, I did not touch the group permissions at all. At the same time I set the (disabled) guest account to "no access" on all these shares. I have not enabled ACL on the shares yet.

Even though I did this the files and folders I create in these shares from a Windows 7 installation are created world writeable (777). I mounted the share in linux and created a text file which looked a little bit better, but it was still "644". How can I set the default creation mask of the entire share to prevent the world from any access at all to the share?

I enabled SSH access and tried editing the /usr/syno/etc/smb.conf, but as someone said in another post on the Synology forum, that file is overwritten on a restart of the NAS.

[Synology forum post](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=75273)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer: Not possible.

I tried changing settings with `synoacltool`while waiting for a reply from the Synology support, but just as I thought I had managed to fix it, mounting it Windows and creating files/folders showed that I was back where I started.

This is the answer I got from the Synology support:

*Since the rules you would like to setup will cause conflicts due to the privilege priority is as follow: No access > Read/Write > Read only.
- RW: users group
- NA: everyone (Please be noticed all users account belong to users group by default)
Which means everyone is NOT possible to access the shared folder include admin.*

*In our current design, the default shared folder permission is 777 since we also need to handle different type of permission controls across various platform (windows,Mac and Linux).*